# Waiting for Alamofire in Unit Tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing, alamofire

I'm trying to write a method where a data object (Realm) refreshes it's properties using Alamofire. But I can't figure out how to unit test it.

```
import Alamofire
import RealmSwift
import SwiftyJSON

class Thingy: Object {

    // some properties
    dynamic var property

    // refresh instance
    func refreshThingy() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL)
        .responseJSON {
            response in
                self.property = response["JSON"].string
        }
    }
}
```

In my unit tests, I want to test that the `Thingy` can refresh from server properly.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import XCTest
@testable import MyModule

class Thingy_Tests: XCTestCase {

func testRefreshThingy() {
    let testThingy: Thingy = Thingy.init()
    testThingy.refreshProject()
    XCTAssertEqual(testThingy.property, expected property)
}
```

How do I properly set up unit tests for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `XCTestExpectation` to wait for asynchronous processes, for example:

```
func testExample() {
    let e = expectation(description: "Alamofire")

    Alamofire.request(urlString)
        .response { response in
            XCTAssertNil(response.error, "Whoops, error \(response.error!.localizedDescription)")

            XCTAssertNotNil(response, "No response")
            XCTAssertEqual(response.response?.statusCode ?? 0, 200, "Status code not 200")

            e.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

In your case, if you're going to test your asynchronous method, you have to provide a completion handler to `refreshThingy`:

```
class Thingy {

    var property: String!

    func refreshThingy(completionHandler: ((String?) -> Void)?) {
        Alamofire.request(someURL)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let json = response.result.value as? [String: String] {
                    completionHandler?(json["JSON"])
                } else {
                    completionHandler?(nil)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can test `Thingy`:

```
func testThingy() {
    let e = expectation(description: "Thingy")

    let thingy = Thingy()
    thingy.refreshThingy { string in
        XCTAssertNotNil(string, "Expected non-nil string")
        e.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

Frankly, this pattern of using a completion handler is probably something that you want in your `refreshThingy`, anyway, but I made it optional in case you might not want to supply a completion handler.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Rob!

Comment: nice trailing closure syntax, instead of `thingy.refreshThingy { (string:String?)->() in`

Comment: Rob, why do you put `5.0` seconds in the `timeout` instead of `1.0` for example?

Comment: @LorenzoBoaro - You want a value large enough that avoids false positives. In my environment, network latency can occasionally (tho rarely) exceed 1 second. And there's generally little downside of using a large timeout because it usually succeeds or fails far quicker than that and never hits the timeout.

Comment: @Rob would it be better (in your opinion) to mock the network request so that it can be returned synchronously and not have to wait for networking at all? I realise you would then have to pass dummy data/JSON whatever back to the requester but is that better than using the actual service?

Comment: I don't think of it as "better", but yes it often makes sense to unit test with stubs. But I still think you should have test suite to do the integration testing, too.

Comment: How to handle "try" inside response closure? I'm getting an error: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(DataResponse<String>) -> Void' The only way to fix this is to use "try?"

Comment: You would wrap that `try` in a `do { ... } catch { ... }` block, catching the error inside the closure and handling it appropriately.