# Unit Test Alamofire request

Tags: unit-testing, swift3, alamofire

I have to test that Alamofire request returns 200 in Swift.
But I don't understand if I have to use my real Request method (and I don't know how because it is obviously asynchronous and at the and it invokes a delegate method) or if I can use another Alamofire call inside the test method. Can you give me a simple example? I don't want to use OHHTTPStubs or other libraries.

Comment: When "unit testing" an asynchronous call, you want to use `XCTestExpectation` to make sure the test doesn't finish before the request does. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34278651/1271826.

Comment: Do you have a sample code that we can use to give you an example?